# How to handle a PSQLException in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, exception

I have a unique constraint on one of my entities and whenever I get a PSQLException which occurs whenever that constraint is violated, I want to respond with a bad request.

This is my exception handler which I tried to implement:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DatabaseExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = PSQLException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handleDatabaseExceptions(PSQLException e) {
        // i want to respond with a bad request only when this condition is satisfied
//
//        if (e.getSQLState().equals("23505")) {
//
//        }
    }

}
```

And this is where the model is saved in db:

```
 public DepartmentForHoliday setDepartment(DepartmentForHoliday department) {
        if (department.getDepartmentId() == null) {
            Department savedDepartment = new Department();
            savedDepartment.setName(department.getName());
            try {
                departmentRepository.save(savedDepartment);
            } catch (PSQLException e) {
              /*here i have a compiler error which says that this exception is never thrown in the corresponding try block, but where ?*/
            }
}
```

This is the exception that is thrown when I add a duplicate entry:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_1t68827l97cwyxo9r1u6t4p7d"
  Detail: Key (name)=(Tech) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2458) ~[postgresql-9.4.1211.jre7.jar:9.4.1211.jre7]
```

How to handle PSQLExceptions ? Should I make my own exception as a wrapper or how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Just catch `SQLException`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "handle" ? What do you want to functionally achieve?

Comment: Same with SQLException, it says that it is never thrown from the corresponding block. I try to respond with a BAD_REQUEST status code when a user tries to enter a duplicate value into DB.

Answer (score 9):

Key problem is that `PSQLException` is wrapped into some Spring exception (which I assume from your code); you have to unwrap it (for example using guava's [`Throwables`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#getRootCause(java.lang.Throwable))):

```
public DepartmentForHoliday setDepartment(DepartmentForHoliday department) {
    if (department.getDepartmentId() == null) {
        Department savedDepartment = new Department();
        savedDepartment.setName(department.getName());
        try {
            departmentRepository.save(savedDepartment);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Throwable rootCause = com.google.common.base.Throwables.getRootCause(e);
            if (rootCause instanceof SQLException) {
                if ("23505".equals(((SQLException) rootCause).getSQLState())) {
                    // do smth interesting :)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you do that you can throw your custom exception and handle it in `DatabaseExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 1):

You are catching PSQLException. Instead of that, please catch SQLException. With SQLException you will can handle all this SQL exceptions.

You can check the SQLException knowledge at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html)

Then in your code just treat the SQLException as you want. The most generic catch clause is the following one:

```
    catch (SQLException e)
   {
   System.out.println("ERROR: Fetch statement failed: " +
      e.getMessage());
   }
```

With this code you are printing the exception. If you want more information, check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite late, but building on previous responses I was able to solve it as so:

```
try {
    return this.projectRepository.saveAndFlush(patchedProjectEntity);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    if (e.getMostSpecificCause().getClass().getName().equals("org.postgresql.util.PSQLException") && ((SQLException) e.getMostSpecificCause()).getSQLState().equals("23505"))
        throw new UniqueConstraintViolationException("", e.getMostSpecificCause());
    throw e;
}
```

Where UniqueConstraintViolationException is a custom exception and handled with a spring controller advice.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well register an exception handler for that wrapped exception (that @radek mentioned) directly.

In your case that's:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException::class)
protected fun handleDataIntegrityException(ex: DataIntegrityViolationException, request: WebRequest) : ResponseEntity<SomeBody>{
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(someBodyHere)
}
```

The error is converted within `convertHibernateAccessException` in `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendorHibernateJpaDialect`, which has already processed away from PSQL. You can add a breakpoint there and follow the stacktrace.

There is a lot of proxy'ing happening under the hood, but the takeaway is that there is always a readable, expressive Exception to use directly.